# How to figure out which function are allowed in the argument 'FUN' of the stat_summary function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to understand how to figure out which functions are allowed in the `fun` and `fun.data` argument in the `stat_summary` function. I was trying to plot the geometric mean of some data, so I installed the package `psych` which has the `geometric.mean` function. I then tried to use this function as an argument in the function (see code) and it worked — it did plot the geometric mean. My question is basically,  why did it work? Is there documentation to figure out what is allowed in the `fun` argument? Because I can't seem to figure it out. I see so many `ggplot` functions with all these possible arguments, `fun`, `fun.data`, `stat` .... but I cannot figure out what to put in there besides the common examples given in the documentation. Is there a comprehensive document that I can reference when I am trying to see all the options for these argument in a function? Please explain it as if you were talking to a golden retriever.

```
library(psych)
library(ggplot2)
df<-mtcars
df$carb<-as.factor(df$carb)
geometric.mean
a <- ggplot(df,aes(carb,hp)) +
  stat_summary(fun = "geometric.mean", geom = "bar")
b<-ggplot(df,aes(carb,hp)) +
  stat_summary(fun = "mean", geom = "bar")
geometric.mean(df[df$carb==4,'hp'])
mean(df[df$carb==4,'hp'])
```

Comment: please note there is mistake in the code, replace 'errorbar' for 'bar'

Comment: Woof woof woof, good dog! Translated: Look at the help for `stat_summary` by typing `?stat_summary`. That notes that `fun.data` is expected to be a function that when given the full data "return[s] a data frame with variables ymin, y, and ymax." It says that `fun` is expected to be a function that receives a vector of values and returns a single number. Within those limits, it sounds like pretty much any function should work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can (and are encouraged) to edit your own question to fix mistakes.

Comment: @JonSpring: please post as answer!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the help for `stat_summary`, a function in `ggplot2`, by typing `?stat_summary` or `?ggplot2::stat_summary`. The "Arguments" section of help files typically explain what the different function arguments mean and what kind of values they expect to receive.

> fun.data
> A function that is given the complete data and should return a data frame with variables ymin, y, and ymax.

> fun.min, fun, fun.max
> Alternatively, supply three individual
> functions that are each passed a vector of values and should return a
> single number.

Here we see that the `fun` argument expects to receive the name of a function which transforms a vector of values into a single number. As long as the function does that, it should work. That probably includes hundreds, if not thousands, of functions from base R and contributed packages.